# Classic to Universal Google Analytics Migration

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I want to migrate classic to Universal Google Analytics tracking, I want to track content and events only for the live domain (not staging):

Currently, I have used method for classic version:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'TRACKING ID']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

I have tried below method but it is not working:

```
ga('create', 'TRACKING ID', {'cookieDomain': '.mydomain.com'});
```

also tried below method:

```
ga('create', 'TRACKING ID', 'auto', {'legacyCookieDomain': 'mydomain.com'});
```

Can you please help on this?

Comment: Why not just add a _filter_ in your **View** settings to include only traffic to hostname "mydomain.com".

Comment: Thanks Aiyanna, i have added Filter to include only my hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I you are using Adwords & Doubleclick you should consider [gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/?hl=en) instead of Universal

Using '**.domain.com**' or '**auto**' on *create event* generates the same result. Check [Google Analytics cookieDomain documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id?hl=en). This option is used in order to share the cookie between subdomains.

If you want to avoid collecting data from other domains or subdomains, use a filter ([include only your domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peBbH.png)).

Comment: Thanks Emirodgar, i have added Filter to include only my hostname